# Stuck alt / modifier key with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a library that creates an editor on the fly (http://epiceditor.com) and also sets up key shortcuts automatically. The shortcuts can be configured in the options so I can't use `e.altKey`, `e.ctrlKey`, etc just a heads up.

For some reason the modifier key isn't being set back to `false` **sometimes** on Mac/Ubuntu browsers.

On Windows it seems to happen every time. You can reproduce this by clicking render in JSBin then pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. You should see "Yay" appear. Now, if on Windows press **just** <kbd>p</kbd> again. You'll see "Yay appear again. Mac and Ubuntu users have seen this same issue occasionally but it's hard to reproduce it.

Also note this only happens with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key it seems. Below I have 16 (shift) next to the 18 (alt). If you swap those out it'll work as expected.

The code for the stripped down test case is:

```
var modKey = false;
var modKeyCode = 18; //16
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (!modKey && modKeyCode == e.keyCode) {
    modKey = true;
  }
  
  if (modKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
    console.log('Yay!');
  }
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (modKey && modKeyCode == e.keyCode) {
    modKey = false;
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uhupah/3/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a fix, albeit a sort of crappy fix, but a fix nonetheless.

The fix I went with was to reset the modifier var when any key combo was successful. I.e. one the `p` in `alt+p` is pressed reset the `modKey` to false like this:

```
var modKey = false;
var modKeyCode = 18; //16
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (!modKey && modKeyCode == e.keyCode) {
    modKey = true;
  }

  if (modKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
    console.log('Yay!');
    modKey = false; //THIS
  }
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (modKey && modKeyCode == e.keyCode) {
    modKey = false;
  }
});
```

The problem with this tho is that you can't do back to back key commands. Most of the time this is alright because the user will do a key command like "save" or "preview" or something, type some more, then do another key command. But you wouldn't be able to, let's say: `alt+p s` to trigger `alt+p` then `alt+s` without having to let go of the `alt` key.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to my Linux box at the moment, so i cannot test your code.

Thus here is more of a suggestion:

Linux (in my experience) is finicky when it it comes to keyCodes and order of key events. Perhaps combine the if(..) from keyup with that of keydown

```
if (!modKey && modKeyCode == e.keyCode) {
  modKey = true;
} else if (modKey && modKeyCode == e.keyCode) {
  modKey = false;
}
```

The above suggestion is made with assumption that you have no specific requirement to have both 'keydown' and 'keyup'.

Comment: Same issue: http://jsbin.com/uhupah/4/edit -- thats if i move all the code to a keydown. The issue is more with Windows that Linux or OS X since those happen less frequently.

Comment: @OscarGodson wow! Not being able to consistently reproduce the error does make it difficult to solve for. Hope your fix is sufficient for your needs.